# How to see missing rows when head() does not work

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not sure if I need to include my dataset for this question, so I'll add it later if it is needed. I have run the following code and have the following output:

```
MeanResidence <- Fernald_Month %>% group_by(sector) %>% summarise(Month_res_mean = mean(Month_Res))
newdata <- MeanResidence[order(MeanResidence$sector), ]
head(newdata, n = 100)
## # A tibble: 100 × 2
##    sector Month_res_mean
##    <chr>           <dbl>
##  1 B01              127.
##  2 B02              113.
##  3 B03              115.
##  4 B04              123.
##  5 B05              107.
##  6 B06              127.
##  7 B07              142.
##  8 B08              120.
##  9 B09              102.
## 10 B10              141.
## # … with 90 more rows
```

I am just trying to see all 100 rows of the mean residence time in months. However, I tried doing the head command with n being 100, since just running the newdata line did not display all 100 rows, but the head function does not seem to work here. What function can I use to see the other 90 rows that are not shown?

Comment: Try `head(as.data.frame(newdata), 100)`

Comment: If you are using RStudio, maybe you want `View()`

Comment: Use `print(newdata, n = 100)` rather than `head()`